# Converting docx/pdf file in s3 to txt file and storing in s3 using python + boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docx, boto3

My situation is that I have docx/pdf files stored in S3. I need to convert these file into txt file and then store the converted file in S3. I am using docx2txt library (docx2txt 0.5: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/docx2txt/). Below is my code and the error:

```
import boto3
import docx2txt
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('client-shared-file')
obj = s3.Object(bucket.name, 'key name');
text = docx2txt.process(obj.get()['Body']) //I also tried .read() but still not work
print(text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    text = docx2txt.process(obj.get()['Body'])
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx2txt\docx2txt.py", line 76, in process
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(docx)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1089, in _RealGetContents
    endrec = _EndRecData(fp)
  File "...\Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 241, in _EndRecData
    fpin.seek(0, 2)
AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'seek'
```

This is the Object:

```
{
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        'RequestId': 'RequestId', 
        'HostId': 'HostId', 
        'HTTPStatusCode': 200
        }, 
    'AcceptRanges': 'bytes', 
    'Metadata': {}, 
    'ContentType': 'application/msword', 
    'ContentLength': 66235, 
    'Body': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x00000219C885FF28>, 
    'ETag': '"ETag"', 
    'LastModified': 'LastModified'
}
```

It seems like the boto3 StreamingBody could not be used as docx file in docx2txt function. Is there anyway to convert these files on s3 or what did I do wrong in the process? Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry but why do I get a downvote? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamingBody` is not a seekable file, which docx2txt seems to want. You will need to buffer the entire file into something else. A `BytesIO` might work, for instance.

Comment: could you help me in converting StreamingBody to BytesIO process?

Comment: Philips I use the following code `text = docx2txt.process(io.BytesIO(obj.get()['Body'].read()))` and it comes up with this error: _Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    text = docx2txt.process(io.BytesIO(obj.get()['Body'].read()))
  File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\docx2txt\docx2txt.py", line 76, in process
    zipf = zipfile.ZipFile(docx)
  File "Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "Anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py", line 1093, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")_

Answer (score 4):

```
body=obj.get()['Body'].read()
buffer = io.BytesIO()
buffer.write(body)
text = docx2txt.process(buffer)
```

Convert the object to **BytesIO** like shown in the above code.